# Installed Ubuntu, Unable to open Windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I got bored with the Windows 8 and tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I had trouble installing it and looked for help. I learnt that I had to make the root as "/" and format the drive as Ext 2 or 3 or 4.

Now that I have installed my Ubuntu, I can't multi-boot into Windows 8. So I decided to open Disk utility. This showed that the major part of my HDD was in the Ext2 type, I reformatted that partition to NTFS (as I wanted to format Windows 8). Still no change - "Windows needs a missing partition"

I put in the Win 8 installation disc, but I can not see my HDD.

I just want to make the Windows partition visible, and reinstall Windows 8 in that.

I don't have access to internet on Ubuntu as I can't install my wireless modem.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) from Ubuntu. This will produce a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to a pastebin site (such as [this one](http://paste.ubuntu.com/)) and report back with the URL. This will give us information about your current configuration. Without that information, any answer will be based on guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinstalling windows, try repairing it.
Boot from your win8 dvd, advanced options/ repair, and choose automatic repair.
After that if you want to install Ubuntu, download 13.04 64 bit and read carefully before installing!